# My decoration image is not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, assets, decoration

```
Card(
                      child: Container(
                      height: 250,
                      width: 180,
                        //color: Colors.pink,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              height: 190,
                              width: 160,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                 // color:Colors.white,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image:AssetImage("assets/images/hamlogo.png"),),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text("\AED 30.00",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                          ],
                        ),
                    ),),
```

pubspec

flutter:

## The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is

## included with your application, so that you can use the icons in

## the material Icons class.

uses-material-design: true

## To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

assets:

- assets/images/hamlogo.png

  - assets/images/ring.png
- assets/images/dnek.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting asset correctly, follow this:

first you need create a asset folder in your project root folder, like this:

[image]

then in your `pubspec.yaml` , under `flutter:` define it like this:

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

[image]

then run `flutter pub get` now if you call image, you can see it:

```
Card(
        child: Container(
          height: 250,
          width: 180,
          //color: Colors.pink,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 190,
                width: 160,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // color:Colors.white,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/test.jpeg'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "\AED 30.00",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

**Note:** if you still not getting image, please stop project and close ide, then open it again run flutter pub get then run then project.

Comment: I have above issue. my code is working on another file but when I use same to same code in different file then image not display clearly, Image loaded but its display blurry.
Output image : https://imgur.com/a/v2SfYxf  and Actual Image: https://imgur.com/sf11kCd